# How do I disable brace highlighting in JetBrains RubyMine?

Tags: rubymine

I want to disable brace contents highlighting in RubyMine. It's very distracting. Instead of having the entire string highlighted I only want the braces themselves highlighted and if that is not possible I need it disabled. Is this possible?

Things I've done already to no success:

- Enabled/disabled all highlight options under Settings/General to no
  effect. I'm running RubyMine v8.0.3.
- Read the documentation.
  jetbrains.com/idea/help/highlighting-braces.html?search=highlighting
- I've also read this document that states how to disable highlighting
  of usages by simply pressing escape - it does not work.
  jetbrains.com/idea/help/highlighting-usages.html#3

[current brace highlighting that I need disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOeYF.png)

Comment: _Settings/General_: Did you mean _Settings/Editor/General_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file type seems to be HAML.

In `Settings`, go to `Editor > Colors & Fonts > HAML`. In the lower right area, you see demo code in HAML. Look for the right spot in the code and click on it.

You will probably click on the second line because there is some code in braces. In this case, RubyMine will select the entry `Injected code` in the list. The check box *Use inherited attributes* tells you that this settings is inherited.

Now you have to choose:

- If you want to change the setting for `Editor > Colors & Fonts > HAML - Injected code`, switch off *Use inherited settings*, then switch off "Background".
- If you want to the settings for injected code in all languages: Click on the link "General" (on the right). RubyMine will switch to `Editor > Colors & Fonts > General - Injected language frament`. Now switch off "Background"

*Before* modifing anything, you have to create a new scheme. The default scheme is read only. Click on `Save As...`, choose a name and press 'OK'.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Settings/Preferences dialog.
In the Editor page of the IDE Settings, select the check box Highlight usages of element at caret to enable automatic usage highlighting.